# How to resolve missing android build tools on circleci2.0 android build?

Tags: android, build.gradle, android-build, circleci-2.0

I'm running an android build with circleci 2.0 and get an error about missing build tools `failed to find Build Tools revision 24.0.1` using the `circleci/android:api-24-node8-alpha` docker image.

I find an old solution for this but it targets the 1.0 cicrcleci instead of 2.0. - https://discuss.circleci.com/t/installing-android-build-tools-23-0-2/924 .

I tried the fix in the question but `dependencies` doesn't seem to be picked up in the YAML as suggested in the above link.

**Question:**
Any idea why the build tools aren't being picked up in the circleci/android docker image?

The error is get exactly in circleci workflow is as follows:

```
command: ./gradlew androidDepedencies
```

error:

> Configuring > 2/3 projectsFAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>   * What went wrong:
>   A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
>   failed to find Build Tools revision 24.0.1

This is my android job spec and a link to [my repo config.yam](https://github.com/BrianJVarley/react-native-prototyping/blob/master/.circleci/config.yml)l:

```
 android:
    working_directory: ~/repo/android
    docker:
      - image: circleci/android:api-24-node8-alpha
    dependencies:
      pre:
        - echo y | android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter "tools"
        - echo y | android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter "build-tools-24.0.1"
    steps:
      - checkout:
          path: ~/repo
      - restore_cache:
          key: jars-{{ checksum "build.gradle" }}-{{ checksum  "app/build.gradle" }}
      - attach_workspace:
          at: ~/repo
      - run: echo 'export TERM=xterm' >> $BASH_ENV
      - run: sudo chmod +x ./gradlew
      - run: ./gradlew androidDepedencies    
      - run: ./gradlew assembleRelease
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the 'dependencies' can be avoided in CCI2.0.

> dependencies:
>         pre:
>           - echo y | android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter "tools"
>           - echo y | android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter "build-tools-24.0.1"

As you know the CCI2.0 works on a docker image-based system. You can find docker image files [here](https://github.com/CircleCI-Public/circleci-dockerfiles/tree/master/android/images) and [here](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/circleci-images/#android).
If you look into the DockerFile you can see all code which accepts licences and updates the SDKManager.

You may need to follow steps like

- code check out
- restore cache
- download dependencies
- save cache
- assemble release

> ```
> steps:
>   - checkout
>   - restore_cache:
>       key: jars-{{ checksum "build.gradle" }}-{{ checksum "app/build.gradle" }}
>   - run:
>       name: Download Dependencies
>       command: |
>               sudo chmod +x gradlew
>               ./gradlew androidDependencies
>   - save_cache:
>       paths:
>         - ~/.gradle
>       key: jars-{{ checksum "build.gradle" }}-{{ checksum  "app/build.gradle" }}
>   - run:
>       name: Take Build
>       command: |
>            ./gradlew clean
>            ./gradlew assembleRelease
> ```

You can find a sample config file [here](https://gist.github.com/SreeAppStore/5a174b34691046878088e34a64c0fb6e)